# ¿Cómo separo una cadena separada por ; y convertilo en cadenas separadas en python?

Tags: python, python-3.7, raspberry-pi

hola estoy programando en python y tengo esta cadena proveniente de un dispositivo que envia por serial 232 a una raspberry

`<001;07-08-21;16:53;   87;   9.76 kg   ;   0.00 kg   ;   9.76 kg   >`

y quiero convertirla en datos individuales para cargar en una base de datos:

```
n=001
fecha= 07-08-21
hora = 16:53
cant = 87
peso1 = 9.76
peso2 = 0.00
peso2 = 9.76
```

Comment: ¿y qué has intentado? deberías poner un código mínimo de lo que has hecho

Comment: `[x.strip() for x in datos[1:-1].split(";")]` es tu punto de partida. `datos` es la línea completa, tal cual la muestras.

Comment: txt ="<001;07-08-21;16:53;   87;   9.76 kg   ;   0.00 kg   ;   9.76 kg   >"
x=txt.split(';')   Gracias compañero asi lo resolvi

Answer (score 0):

Asi lo resolví por si alguien despues ve este post

```
txt ="<001;07-08-21;16:53;   87;   9.76 kg   ;   0.00 kg   ;   9.76 kg   >"
x=txt.split(';')
n = x[0]
fecha = x[1]
hora = x[2]
cant = x[3]
peso1 = x[4]
peso2 = x[5]
peso3 = x[6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Asi lo deje y queda perfecto solo las magnitudes sin signos

```
string ="<001;07-08-21;16:53;   87;   9.76 kg   ;   0.00 kg   ;   9.76 kg   >"
characters = "kg<>  "
for x in range(len(characters)):
    string = string.replace(characters[x],"")
print(string)
x=string.split(';')
d=x[0]
print(d)
fecha=x[1]
print(fecha)
hora=x[2]
print(hora)
cant=x[3]
print(cant)
peso1=x[4]
print(peso1)
peso2=x[5]
print(peso2)
peso3=x[6]
print(peso3)
```

Comment: Edita una respuesta para que toda la informacion esté en una única publicación y elimina la otra

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas puedes compactarlo así:

```py
txt ="<001;07-08-21;16:53;   87;   9.76 kg   ;   0.00 kg   ;   9.76 kg   >"
n,fecha,hora,cant,peso1,peso2,peso3=txt.split(';')
print(n,fecha,hora,cant,peso1,peso2,peso3)
```

Veo que quieres sin magnitudes, como en una respuesta has asumido que solo hay 'kg' y '<' con '>' entonces, asumiendo lo mismo:
Quitamos el primer y último caracter ya que son '<' y '>', luego replazamos 'kg' por ''.

```py
txt ="<001;07-08-21;16:53;   87;   9.76 kg   ;   0.00 kg   ;   9.76 kg   >"
n,fecha,hora,cant,peso1,peso2,peso3=txt[1:-1].replace('kg','').split(';')
print(n,fecha,hora,cant,peso1,peso2,peso3)
```